# Convert disk size from megabytes to gigabytes in KQL query

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have following query that helps me data from vm disk

```
    InsightsMetrics
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk"
| extend Tags = todynamic(Tags)
| extend Drive=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| extend DiskSize=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
| summarize 
Free_space_percentage = avgif(Val, Name == 'FreeSpacePercentage'),
Free_Gigabytes = avgif(Val, Name == 'FreeSpaceMB') /1024
by Computer, Drive
| join (
InsightsMetrics
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk"
| extend Tags = todynamic(Tags)
| extend DiskSize=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
| extend Drive=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
) on Computer, Drive
| where DiskSize has "."
| summarize  by Computer,Drive , Free_space_percentage, Free_Gigabytes, DiskSize
```

Issue is now that DiskSize is displayed in megabytes when all the rest are in gigabytes. I have now tried several hours to try convert it to gigas without luck. Could someone help me where and how should i do my convert in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your issue is not with converting MB to GB, but with structuring a query that will give you the average values as well as the disk size.
Assuming the disks' sizes are not changed during the query period, [take_any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/take-any-aggfunction) will do the trick.

```
InsightsMetrics
// | where TimeGenerated between(datetime(2022-04-01) .. datetime(2022-04-01 00:00:10))
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk"
| extend Tags = todynamic(Tags)
| extend Drive = tostring(Tags["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| extend diskSizeGB = Tags["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"]/1024.0
| summarize 
     avg_FreeSpacePercentage = avgif(Val, Name == 'FreeSpacePercentage')
    ,avg_FreeSpaceGB = avgif(Val, Name == 'FreeSpaceMB') /1024
    ,take_any(diskSizeGB)
    by Computer, Drive
```

| Computer | Drive | avg_FreeSpacePercentage | avg_FreeSpaceGB | diskSizeGB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC00.na.contosohotels.com | C: | 74.9538803100586 | 94.8232421875 | 126.50976181030273 |
| DC00.na.contosohotels.com | D: | 91.4168853759766 | 14.6240234375 | 15.998043060302734 |
| SQL12.na.contosohotels.com | C: | 57.7019577026367 | 72.998046875 | 126.50976181030273 |
| SQL12.na.contosohotels.com | D: | 92.02197265625 | 29.4443359375 | 31.998043060302734 |
| SQL12.na.contosohotels.com | F: | 99.9144668579102 | 127.7626953125 | 127.87304306030273 |
| AppBE01.na.contosohotels.com | C: | 73.2973098754883 | 92.7275390625 | 126.50976181030273 |
| AppBE01.na.contosohotels.com | D: | 91.3375244140625 | 14.611328125 | 15.998043060302734 |

[Fiddle](https://ms.portal.azure.com#@72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade/resourceId/%2FDemo/source/LogsBlade.AnalyticsShareLinkToQuery/q/H4sIAAAAAAAAA31Q0WrCMBR99ysufWkDtabFp0FfOpkI6xgoexki1%252FauBk0qSVqn7OOXtmxuQxbyknPuOfecLJQR1c6anKwWhRl9wGlHmmAlJM1JkUZLJWzJnohUULqXdUyQ8CQZ8%252BmYxwyiCG7gwPmduzFn7Nv0CSWZIxYEaQreY12JAg8zYfaeG6F3S6qEFVYGUrB1eVYoRRF0ALvyMy1a6geMS6yqnn%252F1WhnhRUbSTGTdKLsovfUPUel2LMWF5plT%252FhV8kXnmrScxT6YRd0rTSInawTCC7mBbbR400bLL%252F0y6IGWx6pI4RrwFL3gI%252B4JdN%252F%252FGpM96o%252FCXUR%252FoX4M88xn0sQa5xT1tUJ2Da6fBeHuG%252B1oeG0s6HH7pE%252BgLevzcAQAA)

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: P.S. If you liked the answer, you might consider upvoting it.